# android image not appearing when getting bytes from socket and using bitmap creation

Tags: android, arrays, sockets, decode, bitmapfactory

I have a program in which I'm trying to download the content of an image file from a server. I'm using java socket to download it. After downloading, I use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` to create a bitmap.

At the server side, the file is a **.jpg** file and it's only about 180 KBytes, so I don't need to try scaling it. I can see through logs that the exact number of bytes in the file is received by my image download code. I store all the bytes in a `byte[]` array and then convert it into a bitmap.

The `imageView` is initially hidden and then supposed to be made visible after populating the image. But using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` is returning `null` always. I did see some other posts about null bitmap, but nothing seems to have an answer for this problem.

I don't want to use any external library just for this, so please do not give me suggestions to try out some other libraries. Can someone spot any problem with the code? The server side program is also mine and I know that part is correct because using that, browsers are able to download the same image file. I have copy-pasted it below.

```
public class ImageDownloader {
    private Socket              sockToSrvr;
    private PrintWriter         strmToSrvr;
    private BufferedInputStream strmFromSrvr;
    private String              srvrAddr;
    private int                 port;
    private String              remoteFile;
    private Context             ctxt;
    private Bitmap              imgBmap;
    private View                parkSpotImgVwHldr;
    private View                mngAndFndVwHldr;
    private View                parkSpotImgVw;

    public ImageDownloader(Context c) {
        srvrAddr          = KloudSrvr.srvrIp();
        port              = KloudSrvr.port();
        sockToSrvr        = null;
        strmFromSrvr      = null;
        strmToSrvr        = null;
        remoteFile        = null;
        ctxt              = c;
        imgBmap           = null;
        parkSpotImgVwHldr = null;
        mngAndFndVwHldr   = null;
        parkSpotImgVw     = null;
    }

    public void downloadFile(String remf, View parkSpotImgVwHldrVal,
                 View mngAndFndVwHldrVal, View parkSpotImgVwVal) {
        remoteFile        = remf;
        parkSpotImgVwHldr = parkSpotImgVwHldrVal;
        mngAndFndVwHldr   = mngAndFndVwHldrVal;
        parkSpotImgVw     = parkSpotImgVwVal;

        Thread dwnThrd = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imgBmap = null;
                openServerConnection(); sendReq(); doDownload(); closeServerConnection();
                ((Activity)ctxt).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ((Activity)ctxt).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                mngAndFndVwHldr.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                parkSpotImgVwHldr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(ctxt, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        dwnThrd.start();
    }

    private void sendReq() {
        if(strmToSrvr == null) return;
        String req = "GET /downloadFile " + remoteFile + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
        Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "writing req msg to socket " + req);
        strmToSrvr.write(req); strmToSrvr.flush();
    }

    private void doDownload() {
        boolean gotContLen = false;
        int     contLen    = 0;
        while(true) {
            String inLine = getLine(strmFromSrvr); if(inLine == null) break;
            if((gotContLen == true) &&
               (inLine.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").isEmpty() == true)) break;
            if(inLine.trim().startsWith("Content-Length:") == true) {
                // an empty line after this signifies start of content
                String s = inLine.replace("Content-Length:", "").trim();
                try {contLen = Integer.valueOf(s); gotContLen  = true; continue;}
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {contLen = 0;}
            }
        }
        if((gotContLen == false) || (contLen <= 0)) return;

        byte[]  imgByts  = new byte[contLen];
        int     totRdByts = 0, rdByts, chnk = 1024, avlByts;
        while(true) {
            try {
                avlByts = strmFromSrvr.available(); if(avlByts < 0) break;
                if(avlByts == 0) {try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(InterruptedException ie) {} continue;}
                rdByts = (avlByts < chnk) ? avlByts : chnk;
                rdByts  = strmFromSrvr.read(imgByts, totRdByts, rdByts); if(rdByts < 0) break;
                if(rdByts == 0) {try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(InterruptedException ie) {} continue;}
                totRdByts += rdByts;
                if(totRdByts >= contLen) break;
            } catch(IOException ioe) {return;}
        }
        if(totRdByts < contLen) {
            Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "error - bytes read " + totRdByts
                        + " less than content length " + contLen);
            return;
        }
        if(totRdByts <= 0) return;

        Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "read all image bytes successfully, setting image into view");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByts, 0, contLen, options);
        if(bitmap == null) {Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "got a null bitmap");}
        ((ImageView)parkSpotImgVw).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private void closeServerConnection() {
        if(sockToSrvr == null) return;
        if(strmFromSrvr != null) {
            try {strmFromSrvr.close();}
            catch(IOException e) {Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "Inp strm close exception");}
        }
        if(strmToSrvr != null) strmToSrvr.close();
        try {sockToSrvr.close();}
        catch(IOException e) {Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "Conn close exception");}
        strmFromSrvr = null; strmToSrvr   = null; sockToSrvr   = null;
    }

    private void openServerConnection() {
        try {sockToSrvr = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(srvrAddr), port);}
        catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "Unknown host exception"); sockToSrvr = null; return;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "Server connect exception"); sockToSrvr = null; return;
        }
        Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "Connected to server");

        try {
            strmFromSrvr = new BufferedInputStream(sockToSrvr.getInputStream());
            strmToSrvr = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
                                        (sockToSrvr.getOutputStream())), true);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            closeServerConnection();
            Log.d("IMG-DWNL-LOG: ", "Failed to open reader / writer. Closed the connection."); return;
        }
    }

    private String getLine(BufferedInputStream dis) {
        String outLine = "";
        while(true) {
            try {
                int c = dis.read(); if((c == -1) && (outLine.length() <= 0)) return(null);
                outLine += Character.toString((char)c);
                if(c == '\n') return(outLine);
            } catch(IOException e) {if(outLine.length() <= 0) return(null); return(outLine);}
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making a mistake, assuming that a .jpg file's bytes can be directly decode with the android bitmap decoder. Apparently this is not the case. So, I wrote the received bytes into a temporary file in the phone storage and then called BitmapFactory.decodeFile() which is able to return a good bitmap and ends up showing the image. 
So, have a working solution now.
Still - if anyone has a better suggestion how to decode directly from the received bytes (which are from a .jpg file), I would be very interested to try it out since that would be more efficient. Thanks.